# How to solve this definition of limit proof?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

Let $s: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $$s(x)=\frac{x}{2^x+1}.$$

Prove that

$$\lim_{x\to 0} s(x) = 0$$

I am having trouble using the delta-epsilon definition.

Comment: It may help to notice that for $|x|<1$, we have$$1<2^x+1<3$$ (note the heart on the right side $\color{red}\heartsuit$)

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art, That's not an heart, that's an ice cream

Comment: Ruining the spirit! I'm just trying to be loving, and then I'm told that it isn't a heart but an ice cream? @yanko lol

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt LOL yanko ruined it unforunately haha

Comment: @simplybeautifulart It looks like someone who's sitting upside down.

Comment: @MarkViola You have a wild imagination sir.

Comment: @simplybeautifulart And that's high praise ... isn't it?

Comment: @MarkViola I guess it is $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that for $x\in \Bbb R $,

$$\Bigl| \frac {x}{2^x+1} \Bigr| <|x|$$

so you can take $$\delta=\epsilon $$